# replace componentWillReceiveProps in redux with getDerivedStateFromProps but not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've a problem using `getDerivedStateFromProps` with redux. I want to replace `componentWillReceiveProps` to upgrade to react 16, but somehow it won't fire. Below is my container component code

```
@connect(state=>({user: state.user, global: state.global}), {loginUser})
class LoginFormContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isAuthenticated: false
    }
  }

  //but this worked?
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.user.isAuthenticated !== this.props.user.isAuthenticated && nextProps.user.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.history.location.replace('/dashboard')
    }
  }

  /*static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log('not even fired?')
    if (nextProps.user.isAuthenticated !== prevState.isAuthenticated) {
      return {
        isAuthenticated: '/dashboard'
      }
    }

    return null
  }*/

  handleSubmit() {
    const { email, password } = this.state
    this.props.loginUser(email, password)
  }

  render(){

    this.state.isAuthenticated && <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />

    return(
      <LoginForm />
    )
  }
}

export default LoginFormContainer
```

Comment: What is your version of React, getDerivedStateFromProps is not in version 16 but 16.3.0

Comment: I also want to point out that you don't need to immediately swap your componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps to upgrade to 16.3.0 you can still upgrade without making the switch yet

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.isAuthenticated` is a boolean denoting the authentication status, setting it to `'/dashboard'` in `getDerivedStateFromProps` will not change the route. You'd still have to call `this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')`.

You should change `componentWillReceiveProps` to `componentDidUpdate` for route change actions. Note that you should refer to the updated props with `this.props` and previous props with the first argument of `componentDidUpdate`.

It might be a better idea to perform the route redirect in `loginUser` after successful login, and `componentDidMount` if `isAuthenticated` is cached locally.